# SAS - Sending Email, Whitespace Being Added to HTML

Tags: sas

When I try to send an email of a single HTML character string, SAS inserts a white space character in the middle of the string, throwing the HTML off. For instance, if I run the following code:

```
FILENAME outbox EMAIL
   TO = "address@domain.com" 
   SUBJECT = "test" 
   CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";

DATA _NULL_;
   FILE outbox;
   PUT "<table><tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th><th>column3</th></tr><tr><td>filler</td><td>filler</td><td>filler</td></tr><tr><td>filler</td><td>filler</td><td>filler</td></tr><tr><td>filler</td><td>filler</td><td>filler</td></tr><tr><td>filler</td><td>filler</td><td>filler</td></tr></table>";
RUN;
```

I get the following email, where the table is thrown off because SAS adds a space between `<` and `/td>`.

[image]

I know I could just split up the string, or store it in separate rows of a dataset and send the email that way, but now I'm curious. Does anyone know why SAS does this?

**UPDATE:**

If I format the string differently, like so:

```
DATA _NULL_;
   FILE outbox;
   PUT "<table>
         <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th>
            <th>column3</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
            <td>filler</td>
         </tr>
         </table>";
RUN;
```

The white space is moved to being between the 'f' and 'i' of 'filler' in cell (2,1). I assume this is because of all the extra spaces I added to the string itself to get it formatted that way. It appears to add the white space every 256 characters, no matter the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `</tr>` before `</table>`, and split the string to multiple strings, because "PUT" can accept strings wish have less than 262 characters :

```
    DATA _NULL_;
   FILE outbox;
   PUT "<table>
        <tr>
        <th>column1</th> <th>column2</th> <th>column3</th>
        </tr>";
    put "<tr>
        <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td>
        </tr>";
    put "<tr>
        <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td>
        </tr>";
    put "<tr>
        <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td> 
        </tr>";
    put "<tr>
        <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td> <td>filler</td>
        </tr>
        </table>";
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; the error must have crept in when I was creating the example. Fixing the issue doesn't solve the problem though. And formatting the string differently (like you did) shifts the space around, but it's still there.

Comment: Have you a warning like this "WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  You might have unbalanced quotation 
         marks." ?

Comment: No warning, but there is a note that says that. I'm sure it's splitting it up into 2 strings. I'm just wondering why. If a string variable in a dataset can hold 32767 characters, then why does this split it? Is there a way to stop it from doing that? It's just odd.

Comment: So, I have edited my answer. Try to split the string in multiple PUT.

Comment: I was afraid that that was the only way to fix the issue. oh well. Thanks for talking it through with me!

Comment: You need to add `lrecl=xxx` to the `file outbox` statement, where `xxx` is longer than the length of the put statement, e.g. `file outbound lrecl=10000`

Answer (score 0):

you have forget one of closing table row tag at the end of the table make sure you close all the tags properly then you didn't get any of this  issue in your email.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - that error must have crept in when I was creating the example, but correcting the error doesn't solve the problem...